# C++: Can't have option for Win32 Application

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am currently using Visual Studio Express 2013 (latest) version to start learning C++ coding, but why can't I see the option for creating a new Win32 Application? It would only show an option for Windows Store app?!

Comment: Did you download "Express 2013 for Windows" or "Express 2013 for Windows Desktop" ? -- http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx

Comment: You have the wrong version installed.  You need The Windows Desktop version, not the Windows version.

Comment: ohhhh really? Okay thanks guys, I'm just getting started so... this is a pretty nooby question ^^!